# How to find contact normal and interpenetration depth

Tags: collision-detection, normals

The question is as follows:

Consider a sphere with radius 3 and center point (1,1,1) colliding with the triangular face of an object. The vertices of the triangle are (−3,−3,−7), (3,−3,−1) and (−3,3,−1). Determine the contact normal and the interpenetration depth.

I have no idea how to do this or where to start. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't about programming, but rather mathematics.

Comment: Instead of closing it, maybe point me in the right direction? I tried stack exchange but got nowhere.